# iOS - How to reduce or release memory usage of drawing Unicode emoji?

Tags: ios, swift, memory

On the following code:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
  var counter: Int = 0
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    textView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("onTap:")))
  }
  func onTap(sender: UITextView) {
    if counter % 2 == 0 {
      textView.text = "\(UnicodeEmojiData.ALL_VALUES)"// (a)
      counter = counter + 1
    }
    else {
      textView.text = ""
      counter = counter - 1
    }
  }
```

#### On the start-up

memory usage: 7.35MB...(1)

UITextView does not have any text.

#### On the first tap

memory usage: 18.13MB...(2)

UITextView has all Unicode emoji.

#### On the second tap

memory usage: 14.24MB...(3)

UITextView does not have any text.

## Questions

- Why does not the memory usage go back to previous usage? (If (a) is normal ASCII character, it goes back to previous usage.)
- How can I get it back to previous usage?

By the way, it seems that emoji is drawn as a bitmap internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way to uncache fonts (which what you're trying to do). This is handled by the Core Text system, and once it takes the trouble to figure out a character, it likes to hold onto it.

If this causes issues, you should open a radar (bugreport.apple.com) and report it.